# Error: Target container is not a DOM element. Trying to render data on click to a div with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, render

Using react with gatsby as backend for layout management. I am running into the DOM element error by using ReactDOM.render(

```
<SSection>
        <Grid itemMaxWidth={200} gap={30}>
          {WALLETS.map((app) => (
            <a
              key={app.name}
              href={app.url}
              target="_blank"
              onclick={
                ReactDOM.render(
                     pi,
                     document.getElementById('app')
                 )
               }
              rel="noreferrer noopener"
            >
              <SApp>
                <SAppIcon {...app.style}>
                  <img src={app.icon} alt={app.name} />
                </SAppIcon>
                <SAppName>{app.name}</SAppName>
              </SApp>
            </a>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </SSection>
```

In my layouts:

```
  <SFlex>
    <SContent>
      <Header pathname={location.pathname} />
      <SContainer><div id="app"></div></SContainer>
      <SContainer>{children}</SContainer>
      <Footer pathname={location.pathname} />
    </SContent>
  </SFlex>
```

So the render is not rending to the ID of app.

Comment: If you run `document.getElementById('app')` in dev tools before clicking the button, do you get element all right?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova not sure how to do this, sorry new to this

Comment: Just paste that into the Chrome's devtools console (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console)

Comment: Yeah that works and returns the exact div :)

Comment: Should work then. Can you make a sanbox to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Can I make this in site on stackoverflow?

Comment: Easiest would be jsfiddle, codesandbox or similar

Comment: I am not going to be able to do this as there is too much code and resources. it makes 0 sense when the element is on the page but it is showing onclick as now (anonymous function)

Comment: Well, you can either debug this (they adding `console.log(document.getElementById('app'))` to the onClick right before calling `render`) or try something else( will portals work for you https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html ?) But as you say, it doesn't make any sense to without seeing it actually happening, I doubt anyone will be able to help.